# Talend - URI based on values obtained from a list

Tags: json, web-services, talend

I need to feed a collection in MongoDB based on values obtained from webservices that provide JSON, but I'm having trouble mounting the job because the URI of some of the web services rely on values that can be obtained from other webservices.
For example, the URI http://172.31.15.180:80/ws/getAgenciasUF/52 provides a JSON with a collection, in this format:

```
{ "COD_AGENCIA", "521800300", "NAME", "PORANGATU", "UORG": "902", "INTRA_MUNICIPAL": "0"},
{ "COD_AGENCIA", "521830000", "NAME", "HOLD", "UORG": "904", "INTRA_MUNICIPAL": "0"}
...
(20 other values)
...
```

Through this webservice, I could have insert in a MongoDB collection using the tREST and tExtractJSONFields components.
However, there is another webservice whose URI is http://172.31.15.180:80/ws/getCidadesPorAgencia/521800300, where the latter value is one of COD_AGENCIA available in JSON above. That is, if I read the COD_AGENCIA up and put in some component that iterate on these values and shoot x times the second URI, varying only the code, I could get all the values needed to feed another collection MongoDB.

Using the ESB TOS 6.2.1, I tried to interconnect a Trest a tExtractJSONField and this to a tRESTRequest, like this:

[image: my job]

but I received the following error:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3587
[statistics] connected

[WARN ]: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED SelectChannelConnector@172.31.15.180:80: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:472)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:175)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
at bdogo.teste_0_1.teste$Thread4RestServiceProviderEndpoint.run(teste.java:791)

[WARN ]: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@13df084: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:472)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:175)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
at bdogo.teste_0_1.teste$Thread4RestServiceProviderEndpoint.run(teste.java:791)

[ERROR]: org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine - Could not start Jetty server on port 80: Cannot assign requested address: bind
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
at bdogo.teste_0_1.teste$Thread4RestServiceProviderEndpoint.run(teste.java:791)

Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not start Jetty server on port 80: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:483)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:175)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
... 1 more

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:472)
... 7 more
```

If I eliminate tRESTRequest and link the tExtractJSONField directly to tLog this error doesn't happen, and the output of tExtract is listed on the console. The use of this tRESTRequest component (which is new to me) is that I seem to be something wrong. It is so even that it should be used (see figure below)?

[image: tRESTRequest]

Note that there is a warning in tExtractJSONFields (the text says: "This component has not enough Row type outputs"). The following figures shows as the configuration of the components was made.

Could help me on how to configure it from values  received from tExtractJSONFields?
What am I doing wrong? There is another way to get the desired result ?

Comment: tRestRequest component is used when you want to provide a Webservice. Here it seems that you want to consume both webservices, then I think you should use tRestClient instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, you only seem to lack a few components.

**Job design**

1. Get list of `COD_AGENCIA`

The components *tREST* and *tExtractJSONFields* are well suited for this.

At this point you should have a list of all the values you got with the first REST call.

Now for the connection between the first and the second call.

2. Get list of `getCidadesPorAgencia` per `COD_AGENCIA`

Here, you could again use a *tREST* component and maybe a *tExtractJSONFields*. Also, here would be the spot where to use *tMongoDBOutput*.

To connect both of those requests, use a *tFlowToIterate* component after the first *tExtractJSONFields*.

Add a key value for `COD_AGENCIA` and connect the second *tREST* with *Iterate*. Now in the second *tREST* you will have access to a global variable which you just named as the key value. Use this in the call, e.g.: `"http://172.31.15.180:80/ws/getCidadesPorAgencia/" + globalMap.get("var_agencia")"`

Now you should be able to loop through every agency and get all the cities connected to it.

**Reason**

What you did was a great idea but the wrong connector. *OnComponentOk* waits until the connected component runs through without an error. Then the next component will be started. No data will be transmitted. And *no row iteration will happen*, which seems to be key here.

Comment: Thank you so much, tobi6, your tips helped a lot! I managed to get all the cities and print them on a tLog. However, the job brings all values ​​at once. As I would, for every iteration, prepare the values ​​of each agency to enter into separate collections? In other words, each iteration (every agency), able to generate a JSON with values ​​separated by agency , then insert the MongoDB ?

Comment: When replacing the tLog for tFileOutputJSON, the generated file contained only the last iteration cities. How to generate multiple JSON objects, one for each agency and its collection of cities?

Comment: No problem. This depends strongly on your job design and your requirement, which I didn't understand completely. Every agency should provide its values already and be one entity to put into MongoDB.

Comment: If you use a *tFileOutputJSON* (which you don't need in my opinion) then you need to change the filename dynamically as well.

Comment: The problem is not to change the name of file dynamically, but generate multiple JSON (one for each agency), or a single JSON but with various objects inside (an agency with a collection of cities). But I appreciate your help, I will create another topic with this problem, to become more clear. Thank you!